# Polarized trace

Tags: polarization, spinors, dirac-matrices, trace

Lets say I want to calculate the following Trace

$\mathrm{Tr}[u^{s_1}(p)~\bar{u}^{s_2}(p)~\gamma^{\mu}\not p~ \not q~ \not p~ \gamma^\nu]$

Now if I consider unpolaized case then $s_1=s_2=s$ and I simply sum over s, which
means I can use the completeness relation

$\sum_s u^{s}(p)~\bar{u}^{s}(p)= \not p~ + m $

Now the trace is solvable by applying trace identities of gamma matrix.

OK the question is that I want to calculate the same trace but for a particular polarization state for the spinors i.e for $s_1=\uparrow$ and $s_2 =\downarrow$

So how to calculate this polarized trace without using the explicit spinor representation

$\mathrm{Tr}[u^{\uparrow}(p)~\bar{u}^{\downarrow}(p)~\gamma^{\mu}\not p~ \not q~ \not p~ \gamma^\nu]$

Answer (score 0):

As you said, one way would be to specify a matrix representation for the spinors but it restrains the study. Another way lies on using the helicity projection operators to define a particular polarization. This method leads to traces solvable by applying $\gamma$-matrices identities, so this is a pretty convenient way.

**The helicity projection operators**

We note the longitudinal spin component $\sigma_{\textbf{p}} = \frac{\mathbf{\sigma}\mathbf{.p}}{|\mathbf{p}|}$ and we define the helicity projection operators by
$$ \Pi^{\pm}(\mathbf{p}) = \frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \sigma_\mathbf{p}) $$
Those operators project the spinors over the parallel (or antiparallel) spin to the direction of motion, as shown in the following identities (where the index r stands for the spin states $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$).
$$ \Pi^+(\mathbf{p})u_r(\mathbf{p}) = \delta_{r\uparrow}u_r(\mathbf{p})=u_\uparrow(\mathbf{p})$$
$$ \Pi^-(\mathbf{p})u_r(\mathbf{p}) = \delta_{r\downarrow}u_r(\mathbf{p})=u_\downarrow(\mathbf{p})$$
$$ \Pi^+(\mathbf{p})v_r(\mathbf{p}) = \delta_{r\downarrow}v_r(\mathbf{p})=v_\downarrow(\mathbf{p})$$
$$ \Pi^-(\mathbf{p})v_r(\mathbf{p}) = \delta_{r\uparrow}v_r(\mathbf{p})=v_\uparrow(\mathbf{p})$$

The idea is to use those operators in order to replace the specific spinor spin states by a sum over all states (where the Kronecker delta keep track of the specific state) so that you still have a sum over all states which leads to a trace when one applies the completeness relations. I will give an example to illustrate how it works. I don't really understand where the trace you get in your question comes from, so I assume you obtained it squaring the unpolarized Feynman amplitude. If it the case I hope my example will help you, otherwise this is irrelevant...

Let consider that we have a Feynman amplitude $\mathcal{M} = \bar{u}_\downarrow(\mathbf{p'})\Gamma u_\uparrow(\mathbf{p})$ given for a particular polarization state (I have chosen a flip of spin state to fit your example) where $\Gamma$ is a $4x4$ matrix built up out of $\gamma$-matrices. We introduce $\tilde{\Gamma} = \gamma^0\Gamma^\dagger\gamma^0$ which enables us to write the square amplitude as 
$$|\mathcal{M}|^2 = (\bar{u}_\downarrow(\mathbf{p'})\Gamma u_\uparrow(\mathbf{p}))(\bar{u}_\uparrow(\mathbf{p})\tilde{\Gamma} u_\downarrow(\mathbf{p'}))$$
We are free to rewrite this expression introducing the helicity projection operators (they will not contribute since the positive (negative) operator acts on the positive (negative) spin state):
$$|\mathcal{M}|^2 = (\bar{u}_\downarrow(\mathbf{p'})\Gamma\Pi^+(\mathbf{p}) u_\uparrow(\mathbf{p}))(\bar{u}_\uparrow(\mathbf{p})\tilde{\Gamma}\Pi^-(\mathbf{p'}) u_\downarrow(\mathbf{p'}))$$

We can now sum over the spins because thanks to the helicity projection operators only one of the four terms is nonzero.

$$|\mathcal{M}|^2 = \sum_{r = \uparrow \downarrow}\sum_{s = \uparrow \downarrow}(\bar{u}_s(\mathbf{p'})\Gamma\Pi^+(\mathbf{p}) u_r(\mathbf{p}))(\bar{u}_r(\mathbf{p})\tilde{\Gamma}\Pi^-(\mathbf{p'}) u_s(\mathbf{p'}))$$

We can now write this expression as a trace. For that we should write down the spinors indices, move $u_s(\mathbf{p'})$ to the left and use the completeness relations. Doing that we obtain :

$$|\mathcal{M}|^2 = Tr[(\not{p'} +m)\Gamma\Pi^+(\mathbf{p})(\not{p} +m)\tilde{\Gamma}\Pi^-(\mathbf{p'})]$$

This expression can now be computed using $\gamma$-matrices identities and trace technology. By the way, in the relativistic limit $E\gg m$ the helicity projection operators simplify to

$$ \Pi^{\pm}(\mathbf{p}) = \frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \gamma^5) $$

which leads to a considerable simplification during the computation of the trace.

As a conclusion, for a definite polarization the idea is to compute the trace as usual projecting over the relevant spin states via the helicity operators. I hope this answers your question, but I might be wrong when I try to understand where your trace comes from.